# Rails 4 has_many through naming

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, associations, has-many

I'm having problems with a Rails 4 join table. I have quite a simple setup which is working elsewhere in my application using a non-conventionally named table for users, groups and usergroupmemberships. I'm trying to set it up this time using the proper conventional naming and it's just not working.

Models involved are User, ManagementGroup and ManagementGroupsUser
db tables: management_groups_user, management_groups, users

app/models/user.rb

```
Class User < ActiveRecord::Base
...
  has_many :management_groups, through: management_groups_users
  has_many :management_groups_users
....
```

app/models/management_group.rb

```
class ManagementGroup < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :users, through: :management_groups_users
  has_many :management_groups_users
```

app/models/management_groups_user.rb

```
class ManagementGroupsUser < ActiveRecord::Base

  belongs_to :users
  belongs_to :management_groups
```

The association appears to work from with @user.management_groups_users but nothing else. I'm fairly sure this is a problem with naming / plurality but I can't figure it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**This is the model which joins the remaining models user.rb and management_group**

```
#app/models/management_groups_user.rb
belongs_to :user
belongs_to :management_group
```

**Since we are going to use model above to access another model management_group then**

```
#app/models/user.rb
has_many :user_management_groups  #This should come first  
has_many :management_groups, through: user_management_groups
```

**Since we are going to use model above to access another user model then**

```
app/models/management_group.rb
has_many :user_management_groups
has_many :users, through: :user_management_groups
```

Now should work

Comment: Thanks Pradeep, after finding the error with the belongs_to relationships being plural and not singular this is how my code looks now. FYI I tested the ordering of the has_many lines and it doesn't appear to make much difference.

Comment: This is accepted answer but doesn't have any vote up, Other answers have tons of voteup, really wierd @stackoverflow

Answer (score 1):

It's important to realize there is a convention rails uses for HABTM and has many through. HABTM does not have a model, so it needs to infer the table name which, as others point out, is both plural and alphabetical order.

If you are doing has many through and have a model, the convention is that it wants singular first word, plural second. See examples

User has and belongs to many groups.

**HABTM**: table name should be groups_users

**Has Many Through**: table name should be user_groups (flip order is more intuitive)

Model for the latter would be UserGroup. Has many through would specify it as `through: :user_groups`

Answer (score 0):

Do it this way.

app/models/user.rb

```
has_many :user_management_groups    
has_many :management_groups, through: user_management_groups
```

app/models/management_group.rb

```
has_many :user_management_groups
has_many :users, through: :user_management_groups
```

app/models/management_groups_user.rb

```
belongs_to :user
belongs_to :management_group
```

I hope these associations will help you.

Comment: Hi, thanks for taking the time to help out. Your suggestions on the first two files wouldn't work because they don't match the db name / conventions but you did highlight an error I made. The association I used for 'belongs_to' used plural form for the tables when they should be singular. Changed this and it's all working :)

Comment: Add third table name UserManagementGroup. The above code will work.

Comment: This way

app/models/management_groups_user.rb


`self.table_name = 'user_management_groups'`

Answer (score 0):

This is another way if you pass foreign key and class name.

app/models/user.rb

```
has_many :user_management_groups, :foreign_key => "key", :class_name => "ClassName"     
has_many :management_groups, through: user_management_groups, :foreign_key => "key", :class_name => "ClassName"
```

app/models/management_group.rb

```
has_many :user_management_groups
has_many :users, through: :user_management_groups
```

app/models/management_groups_user.rb

```
belongs_to :user, class_name: "ClassName"
belongs_to :management_group, class_name: "ClassName"
```

This is another way around.